# SQLite/Android - Insert values from SQL file with accents

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Im trying to setup my app with an SQLite database, and populate the same DB with some values. To populate the tables i have two methods:

1. Use the .insert() method from my object DAO (the values are define in Java code);
2. Read .sql file placed inside Assets folder, and execute each line using:

   db.execSQL(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));

Using the 1st option i am able to insert values like "sé", "são", "ç", and when i retrieve from DB this same values i got them exactly the way i wrote them.

Using the 2nd option (read from file), the value is inserted with the symbol "?", for example: "s?", "s?o", "?".

This is my .sql file:

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";
INSERT INTO [DEPARTMENT] ([depID], [DEP_NAME]) VALUES (111, 'Informática');
INSERT INTO [DEPARTMENT] ([depID], [DEP_NAME]) VALUES (222, 'Cívil');
```

This is my method to read the file:

```
private void insertValues(boolean fromFile) throws IOException {
        if (!fromFile) {
             // option one working...
        } else {

        InputStream script = this.getAssets().open("sql_script.sql");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        for (int byteRead = script.read(); byteRead != -1; byteRead = script
                .read()) {
            // resets the buffer
            Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);

            // reads a SQL statement to the buffer
            for (int i = 0; byteRead != -1 && i != 1024; byteRead = script
                    .read(), i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) byteRead;

                if (byteRead == ';')
                    break;
            }

            // execute the SQL statement from the buffer
            if (byteRead != -1)
                db.execSQL(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
        }
    }
}
```

i tried to use `new String(buffer, "UTF-8")` but it also didnt work.

Comment: What is the encoding used in your .sql file?

Comment: my sql file starts with: PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";

Comment: That doesn't specify the encoding the file is saved in; it just tells the sqlite the [encoding to create the database in](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding). You don't need to specify it yourself. Let the Android SQLLite API handle encoding settings for you.

Comment: ok, so i encoded my file to UTF-8, but i have the same result as before: "?" instead of accent letter.

Comment: @laalto you were right, i checked and even that i modify the encoding file in some editor (notepad++) as UTF-8 it is imported to eclipse as default encoding (Cp1252). I went to .sql file inside assets -> Properties ->Text file encoding -> Other -> UTF-8. Solved my problem! Thanks